# Need a regex to modify a second match and ignore the first and last

Tags: regex, find-occurrences, marc

Library context, using MarcEdit which can also use regex.

I need this:

```
=773 \\$tEtudes inuit$x0701-1008$1Vol. 44 1-2, $2p. 53-84
```

to be changed to this:

```
=773  \\$tEtudes inuit$x0701-1008$1Vol. 44, no. 1-2, $2p. 53-84
```

Problem is, the 44 in this case and the 1-2 are numbers that will change from one book to the other and I am building commands to automate it.

I tried focusing on changing the space between the 44 and the 1-2 into a ', no. ' with \s but it obiviously changes all spaces characters.

The adding ', no. ' is easy because there is a different box for it but I can't focus on the 2nd space while ignoring the first and last and also keeping every characters before and after.

Thank you for helping, I've been looking/trying all day!

[MarcEdit exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv8ut.png)

Comment: Would you add a more examples, please?
For this example may work: `([\d]+)[ ]+([\d]+)` with replace pattern `$1, no. $2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the regular expression implementation supports look ahead, you can require that this space is followed by a range and a comma:

Find: `\s(?=\d+-\d+,)`
Replace: `, no.`